# Problema con componente selector de vuetify, me muestra las opciones pero no me permite seleccionarlas

Tags: vue.js, diseño, vuetify, componentes

El componente selector de vuetify no tiene el comportamiento esperado. el comportamiento errático es que cuando se selecciona un elemento dentro del selector no marca ese elemento ni hace el binding con los atributos del componente Vue

Comment: Muestra el código que tienes hasta el momento para que se te pueda ayudar: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.